# How to stop Sharepoint sending Task overdue emails for completed and deleted Task

Tags: sharepoint-2010, workflow, sharepoint-designer

my issue is the following: I have created workflows in SPD2010 to create Approval Tasks, using the standard 'Start Approval Process' action provided by SPD.
To set the duration per task I'm calculating a variable to set the due date to be Today()+7 days.
In the 'Start Approval Process' sub workflow, 'Change the behavior of a single task' I have added  at the top an action to the set the Field 'Due Date' to equal the mentioned variable.
The problem now is that for tasks that are completed and even removed from the list and recycle bin the system is still sending reminder emails for a task being overdue?

Has anyone any idea what could be causing and how to fix that?

I'm using SharePoint Designer 2010.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove any other version of the same workflow from your screen, go to the following link, look at the last reply

> Blockquote I had come across this issue not too long ago. I was able to find what was causing it in my case. From what I've seen it happens with 2010 workflows and not 2013.

If you go to the list/library that is triggering the workflow and go to List ribbon -> Workflow Settings.

From here you should be able to see the different workflows associated with this list. Now with 2010 workflows, if you make a change and save it, it creates a new version but keeps the old version in this list. You'll be able to see if this is happening easily enough by seeing a timestamp after the name of the workflow.

If you click on Remove, block, or restore a workflow at the bottom, you can see how many instances are currently running, even if they aren't active workflows anymore. This is where my emails were coming from. The old workflows will have No New Instances selected but may still be allowing old ones that were deleted to be running. If you remove all of the old versions, you should stop getting these emails sent out.

https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/64436/deleted-workflows-still-sending-emails